# Scala's way of "while" loops

Tags: scala

If I have this

```
val rdr = new InputStreamReader(intStr)
val buffer = Array[Char](1024)
val stWr = new StringWriter()
```

and I want to do this:

```
//straightforward

var n = 0
while ({ n = rdr read buffer; n != -1 }) {
  stWr write (buffer, 0, n)
}
```

will the following be the idiomatic, Scala's way which I should prefer over the previous approach:

```
//looks better, more idiomatic?
Stream.continually(rdr read buffer) takeWhile (_ != -1) foreach { x =>
  stWr write (buffer, 0, x)
}
```

P.S. Also I am not sure that "x" refers to amount of bytes read (in "foreach"), though, so I'm not sure that these 2 approaches are **exactly** equivalent.

Comment: Your naming does not follow the correct convention. Looks like you reverted my edit. Use names that (in order of quality) a) mirror the business logic or b) full lower camel case of the type or c) initialism of the type. When someone reads your code they will have no idea what the values are unless they read the declaration and thus causing unecessary inconvience and cognition.

Comment: @samthebest, they do follow the correct convention. You're overthinking about that.

Comment: Please provide justification rather than just say you disagree. Google "InputStreamReader example" and find a single page that uses `rdr`. The oracle tutorials (i.e. the bible on this kind of matter) uses `isr` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html

Comment: Similarily for `StringWriter` ... if google for examples you won't see `stWr` you will see `sw`.

Comment: @samthebest, that doesn't mean that stWr is incorrect and everyone must use sw instead of stWr. It's not a rule, it's a recommendation which is not strict. I'm saying again: you're overthinking about that.

Comment: It's a "naming convention" meaning it's *good practice* because (as I have already explained) team members need not spend additional time and cognitive resources understanding your code. Given that following well established conventions requires no effort (just modesty, conscientiousness and team spirit) from your part, there is no argument for _not_ following the convention. Secondly, yes actually it can be a rule and can be strict, it depends on the office.  Maybe as a graduate in a very small team they would allow it, but only by absence of code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more idiomatic solution would be to use a tail-recursive method rather than a while loop. This will also be more efficient that using `Stream.continually`:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def readAll: Unit = {
  val n = rdr.read(buffer)
  if (n != -1) {
    stWr.write(buffer, 0, n)
    readAll
  }
}
readAll
```

Internally, Scala rewrites this as a while loop. What makes this more idiomatic than a while loop is that it allows us to use `val` rather than `var` in most places.  For example, here `n` can be a `val`. More complex examples will have method parameters, these can fill the role of variables that are updated inside the loop.

Comment: Strictly speaking the body of the method is compiled to a "while loop" and therefore you still have one additional method invocation. In fact tail recursion in Scala works by manipulating the stack via overlay. In this use case I doubt it matters, but in general its false to say that performance will be identical to a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly more idiomatic, they are not equivalent, but I believe that's by accident as there is a bug in your `while` loop (see below for correction).  Your Scala Style is a bit off though - your using infix notation too much in that line of code because it's got quite a lot of chaining, so you should stick to dot notation. Also only use curly braces when you need to, otherwise use round braces. So

```
Stream.continually(isr read buffer).takeWhile(_ != -1)
.foreach(x => sw write (buffer, 0, x))
```

But when it comes to code that requires `while`-like behaviour due to the absence of a clear upper bound, it really isn't the end of the world if you use a `while` loop (a lot of the Scala code itself uses `while` loops).  The problem is the `var`, which should be avoided.  Nevertheless for optimized code, one sometimes must use `var`. So, again once we have corrected your style (and the bug) the while is OK also:

```
var n = isr read buffer
while (n != -1) {
  sw write (buffer, 0, n)
  n = isr read buffer
}
```

The bug was you read twice before writing. We could also fix it like this:

```
var n: Int = _
while ({
  n = isr read buffer
  n != -1 
}) {
  sw write (buffer, 0, n)
}
```

One final point, I would actually use dot notation for `read` and `write` methods also, but it's a matter of taste so I've left it as infix.  My argument is that I only use infix notation when the method is being use as though it should be an operator - but that's just my opinion.

Comment: so what's the bottom line? the question isn't about "{" over "(" and using dot notation. I use them because I like that. The question is about "while" loop.

Comment: Well the bottom line is that using `Stream.continually` is more idiomatic but probably wouldn't be picked on in code review for even a senior Scala team. What you _would_ be picked on is incorrect style like unecessary `{}`, using `;`, and overuse of infix notation. The point being using a while loop isn't perfect, but trivial relative to incorrect style.

Comment: One more point ... while loops are probably slightly faster and better for code that needs to be optimized as the `Stream` way will incur a deeper stack (and possibly an additional object on the heap, but i havent read the code for `Stream` in a while (pun intended))

Comment: where did get the point about such a code review by senior developers?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp From personal experience. I've never seen a code rejected based on the use of a while loop over high-order functions. Furthermore I've never seen incorrectly formatted code pass code review.  In fact companies using Sonatype tools for auto style checking would actually make pushing badly styled code impossible.